# JQuery DatePicker 2 Dates Not Working After PrePopulation

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Works right now when you initiate the input

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/rbla/2go9cwca/**

But when I put this code on a page that "updates" and prepopulate the 2 inputs from a DB, the grayed out dates (past the Max and Min) do not work...

```
<input id="datepicker1">

<input id="datepicker2">

<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
    $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
    }
 });
   $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({
   defaultDate: "+1w",
   changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true,
   dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
   onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
   $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
   }
});
});
</script>
```

I expect to see the grayed out dates after the 2 fields get populated with the info from the database, but that is not happening

any ideas ??

Comment: Can you add the code you use to prepopulate the 2 inputs from your DB?

Comment: Not sure, but I think the problem might be with the Event onClose...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go, the problem was your onClose. It has nothing to do with loading the default date or not. The problem is when you open the date picker, and close it without picking a date, selectedDate is nothing. And since you set the minDate / maxDate to nothing, it removes the property minDate/maxDate. You can try it out on your jsFiddle. Open the first date picker, choose a date, open your second date picker, close it without choosing anything and you'll see the min and max are set to nothing.

To fix that, you need to check the value of your selectedDate before updating the date picker.

```
if (selectedDate != "")
```

Here's your fiddle updated: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2go9cwca/1/)

Comment: Thats it - Works great now - I have changed some of the date formatting...   UPDATED DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/rbla/2go9cwca/2/                                      I replace the hard dates with fields from a DB and it works perfectly